WebSphere not installing application
I'm trying to install an application on a new WebSphere environment running on a Docker container. This application is already installed on another WebSphere, but on this container, it gets stuck after ADMA5005I.
Check the SystemOut.log on the deployment manager or server where the application is deployed for specific information about the EJB deployment process as it occurs.

ADMA5016I: Installation of ApplicationPackage started.

ADMA5067I: Resource validation for application ApplicationPackage completed successfully.

ADMA5058I: Application and module versions are validated with versions of deployment targets.

ADMA5005I: The application ApplicationPackage is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.

ADMA5005I: The application ApplicationPackage is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.

ADMA5081I: The bootstrap address for client module is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.

ADMA5053I: The library references for the installed optional package are created.

ADMA5005I: The application ApplicationPackage is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.

ADMA5001I: The application binaries are saved in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/wstemp/1623776755/workspace/cells/DefaultCell01/applications/ApplicationPackage.ear/ApplicationPackage.ear

ADMA5005I: The application ApplicationPackage is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.

SECJ0400I: Successfully updated the application ApplicationPackage with the appContextIDForSecurity information.

ADMA5005I: The application ApplicationPackage is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository. 

Tried

Installation with local file
Installation with remote file
Waiting
Ignored the stuck step, saved and tried to run anyways

All resulted in about the same, application not installed.
Installing another similar application works fine and installs fast. All the logs I've seen showed me barely anything, sometimes it logs that it failed to find a file but the file exists in the EAR so it's not helpful.
I found a FFDC that might be related.
[9/25/24 13:44:02:658 UTC] 000000b5 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5013I: Application ApplicationPackage installed successfully.
[9/25/24 13:44:02:750 UTC] 00000077 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_c49ed029_24.09.25_13.44.02.7131348290461783846678.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.BufferedWriter.writeOut 416

[9/25/24 13:44:02:715 UTC]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.
webcontainer.srt.BufferedWriter.writeOut ProbeId:416 Reporter:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedWriter@1dd78bc8
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write

After some time, it shows Thread "WebContainer : 0" (000000ac) has been active for 697,055 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.

Did you check that archive is not corrupt? e.g. opened with any zip tool?
Also looks like thread is hanging , so you could go into container, do a thread dump and see where it is hanging. But if other similar app installs fine, I would more bet on corrupted file
